# POST HTTP://localhost:53122/albumlist.aspx/www 404 (Not Found)

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

I am using vb.NET .I need to call a function written in albumlist.aspx using jQuery as below:

```
var l = window.location;
var base_url = l.protocol + "//" + l.host;
$(".pagen ").click(function() {
  var num = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + '/albumlist.aspx/www',
    data: {
      id: num
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    encode: true,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
  });
});
```

Function is:

```
Public Function wwww(ByVal id As Integer) As String
    Return "jhgfjhf"
End Function
```

Using this code, getting 'POST http://localhost:53122/albumlist.aspx/www 404 (Not Found)'. What should I do, I am new to vb.

Comment: `wwww` ≠ `www`. Check the `Public Function wwww(` part and `url: base_url + '/albumlist.aspx/www',` part. Let us know if this is the issue. If so, **this question should be closed as a typo**.

Comment: Function name has 4! W in it but you call it with only 3

Comment: ya ,my mistake .But even put  url: base_url + '/albumlist.aspx/wwww  ,the same error resulting

Comment: @neethu What's happening? Show us the logs? Or some screenshot? Did you clear the cache? Recompile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be other problems, but I can spot at least two.  First, you have to mark the method with the `<WebMethod>` attribute.  Second, methods inside of an .aspx page must be marked as `Shared` in order to be visible as web methods.